# Dynamically generated anchor does not post back when id is populated

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Strange. It seems that whenever I populate the id property of a dynamically generated htmlanchor the postback method stops working.

```
        Dim ancAction As New HtmlAnchor
        AddHandler ancAction.ServerClick, AddressOf HandleEditClick
        ancAction.ID = "edit:" & x.xId
        divAction.Controls.Add(ancAction)
```

HandleEditClick will fire when I comment out the line that populates the id property.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It may be because the ID is no longer unique when you manually set it.  ASP.NET doesn't know which control fired if it is not a unique ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use colon in the ID. Make sure your ID is alphanumeric, apparently `__doPostback` doesn't like it otherwise.

Btw, if you use "Edit:" notation as means to later in code know that specific "x.xId": is need editing (you do split string by ":" to get command and argument) there's a better way. Instead of HtmlAnchor use LinkButton, handle LinkButton_Command event and pass "Edit" as CommandName and x.xId as CommandArgument.

Comment: I changed the id to remove the colon and that did the trick. Thank you, Yuriy. Yes, it seems __doPostback is finicky that way. And thanks so much for the extra recommendations!